# Rails & Devise: how to configure mail with domain name automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, engineyard

I need some advice on configuring mail in production Ruby-on-Rails sites.

I deploy my Rails app on EngineYard. I have a couple of sites, like `demo.mydomain.com` or `staging.mydomain.com` - how can I configure Devise so that at deploy time I can make sure confirmation mails come from `demo.mydomain.com` or `staging.mydomain.com` automatically? *ie*, I want the same GitHub codebase, and want to fill the configuration in dynamically.

Currently in `config/environments/production.rb` I have the line:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'demo.mydomain.com' }
```

But that's incorrect when the same code is deployed to `staging.mydomain.com` as they both run in `RAILS_ENV=production`

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Dave

**Update:** For now, to be practical, I've added specific environments to hardcode the mailer domain. So now `demo.mydomain.com` runs on `environments/demo.rb`, and `www.mydomain.com` runs on `environments/productions.rb`. What I *don't* like about this is the duplication between the files, it's not clear to me how to DRY them up as I have with, *eg*, `database.yml`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your devise configuration, usually `config/initializers/devise.rb` you can configure the mail-sender for devise. this configuration takes a proc, so that it's possible to evaluate something at runtime.

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = Proc.new { your_magic_here }
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play on the production box and see if I can figure out the domain - but as far as I can tell, the domain name isn't "visible" on the running box. After all the app could be running on a couple of domains, all handled at DNS level.

Comment: exactly. that's why we setup a global object in each request that holds configurations on a domain basis. this object is then accessed in the proc. the object is similar to what is done in the I18n gem.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally staging & production servers should run on different rails environment. Still if you wanted to have production env running on both staging & production servers with different action mailer urls then it should be done at deployment level. You can always write environment file while deployment.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how I could write an environment file at deployment time? That's the trick I'm missing.

Comment: well. specify host as HOST_URL inside environment file and in your deployment recipe grep file for HOST_URL and replace it wth url you wanted to have based on server(staging,production) to be deployed.
`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'HOST_URL' }`

Comment: Ah, I see. In this case I don't have an explicit recipe to work with ('ey deploy' is how we work), but otherwise that's the tactic I'd have used in other frameworks. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you should separate the environments of your application. Check this [guide](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3535-beyond-the-default-rails-environments) to learn how you can do it.

Then, try something like this in your devise configuration:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  if Rails.env.production?
    config.mailer_sender = "no-reply@domain.com"
  elsif Rails.env.staging?
    config.mailer_sender = "no-reply@staging.domain.com"
  else
    config.mailer_sender = "no-reply@domain.com"
  end
  ...
```

Check this [guide](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/ruby-on-rails-study-guide-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) to understand more about Proc object.